# High Performance Options for Remote services access

Tags: performance, architecture

I have a service, foo, running on machine A. I need to access that service from machine B. One way is to launch a web server on A and do it via HTTP; code running under web server on A accesses foo and returns the results. Another is to write socket server on A; socket server access service foo and returns the result.

HTTP connection initiation and handshake is expensive; sockets can be written, but I want to avoid that. What other options are available for high performance remote calls?

Comment: what do you mean by high performance remote calls? and I dont think there would be one solution fits all for your question. Be more specific.

Comment: I want to use a cache. I did not want to host my own Redis/Memcache. I tried using Elasticache. ElastiCache is usable only from within Amazon Cloud. My clients are outside AWS. There are 10s of clients. So I thought of spinning a EC2 instance and putting something in front of Elasticache. So that something by default is a server like NGinx. Which I can do. But then thought if there is something better. My request rates peak at about 400 rps. My application can tolerate delays of up to like 100-200 ms on cache lookups. At the moment I ended up using a NoSQL DB (dynamo) as my cache.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is just the protocol over the socket.  If you are using TCP/IP networks, you are going to be using a socket.  The HTTP connection initiation and handshake are not the expensive bits, it's TCP initiation that's really the expensive bit.

If you use HTTP 1.1, you can use persistent connections (Keep-Alive), which drastically reduces this cost, closer to that of keeping a persistent socket open.

It all depends on whether you want/need the higher-level protocol.  Using HTTP means you will be able to do things like consume this service from a lot more clients, while writing much less documentation (if you write your own protocol, you will have to document it).  HTTP servers also supports things like authentication, cookies, logging, out of the box.  If you don't need these sorts of capabilities, then HTTP might be a waste.  But I've seen few projects that don't need at least some of these things.

Comment: Well, I have heard that companies such as Facebook have written their own libraries for remote machine service calls. and many other companies have written libraries on top of sockets. Like Yahoo has something called REPL. I was just asking if there is anything in general use out there.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer of  @Rob, as the question is not precisely pointing to an application or performance boundaries, it would be good to look into the options available in a broader context, which is [Inter process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

The wikipedia page cleanly lists down the options available and would be a good place to start with.

Comment: Thank you; but IPC is not really the thing that deals with across machine communications. That is mostly about communication between same machine processes. Say memory mapped file - you need single machine to be able to do that. I am looking for across machine communications. Web services, DCOM, RPC, CORBA etc.

Answer (score 0):

What technology are you going to use? Let me answer for Java world.

If your request rate is below 100/sec, you should not care about optimizations and use most versatile solution - HTTP.

Well-written asynchronous server like Netty-HTTP can easily handle 1000 requests per second on medium-level hardware.

If you need more or have constrained resources, you can go to binary format. Most popular one out there is Google Protobuf(multilanguage) + Netty (Java).

What you should know about HTTP performance:

- Http can use Keep-Alive which removes reconnection cost for every request
- Http adds traffic overhead for every request and response - around 50-100 bytes.
- Http client and server consumes additional CPU for parsing HTTP headers - that is noticeable after abovementioned 100 req/sec
- Be careful when selecting technology. Even in 21 century it is hard to find well-written HTTP server and client.

Comment: My clients are in .Net. I want to use a cache. I did not want to host my own Redis/Memcache. I tried using Elasticache. ElastiCache is usable only from within Amazon Cloud. My .Net clients are outside AWS. So I thought of spinning a EC2 instance and putting something in front of Elasticache. So that something by default is a server like NGinx. Which I can do. But then thought if there is something better. 

My request rates peak at about 400 rps. My application can tolerate delays of up to like 100-200 ms on cache lookups. At the moment I ended up using a NoSQL DB (dynamo) as my cache.

Comment: Take a look at memcached

Comment: Yes, I looked at memcached. The whole thing started when I wanted to avoid hosting my own memcached and started looking at ElastiCache.